# What are the risks of using Gmail for sending email from Craft CMS?

Tags: emails

In [Craft's documentation for email](https://craftcms.com/guides/why-doesnt-craft-send-emails) it says:

> **Gmail** might be a good option depending on your appetite for risk.

But I don't see anything about what the risks are. Is there a risk of getting hacked, or just an increased likelihood of messages not getting through?

I have a small and internal user base, so Gmail might work for me, but I'm trying to make a quick decision and this is making me have to dig for info so I don't make a bad call.

https://craftcms.com/guides/why-doesnt-craft-send-emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly tongue-in-cheek, I think.

When sending emails from Craft using Gmail, Craft uses SMTP, which Gmail considers "insecure", hence the reason they make you enable the "less secure apps" from your Google account.

Comment: Ok, so then are you suggesting there wouldn't likely be actual problems from using Gmail?

Comment: No more problems than email causes in general. :)